# Safe DbContext Disposal

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, interface

I have a service class called `ClientService`, the service class is called using an interface `IClientService`. The service class simply does CRUD methods for the `DbSet<Client>` in my context class.  In my service class constructor I have:

```
private MyContext context;
public ClientService()
{
    context = new MyContext();
}
```

I then have a `void` in the `ClientService` class that can be called from the `IClientService` interface called `Save()` that does this:

```
public void Save()
{
    context.SaveChanges();
    context.Dispose();
    context = new MyContext();
}
```

Is this safe or even necessary or am I good simply saying `context.SaveChanges();` in the `Save()` void?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to call Dispose and new up another context in the Save method. SaveChanges should be good enough.  I would recommend you make ClientService IDisposable and when that class disposes then dispose of the context as well.

**Update from comment**

to implement IDisposable on the IClientService

```
public interface IClientService : IDisposable
```

The will now require a Dispose method on any class that implements IClientService.  In the dispose method you should call the dispose method of the context.

Comment: The problem: `public class ClientService : IClientService`. I'm pretty new with disposing resources so how can I implement the `IDisposable` and my interface at the same time?

Comment: @aaronmallen: A class can implement any number of interfaces. Interfaces are just contracts which specify what methods and properties will be available to be called.

Comment: @ChrisWue so `public class ClientService : IClientService : IDisposable` ?

Comment: I updated my answer with the code.  If you want to make just the class IDisposable and not have it on the interface then you wouljd do public class ClientService : IClientService, IDisposable

Comment: @CharlesNRice: The `IClientInteface` should not derive from `IDisposable` - that's a leaky abstraction.

Comment: @aaronmallen: I think you probably want to check out [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67ef8sbd.aspx) to get an overview of C#

Comment: @ChrisWue my apologies I just realized why you said that. I meant `,` not an initializer. I'm on my phone and had a keyboard fart.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating instance of the context inside the constructor, you can instantiate the context inside the method and then use a `using` block for the safe disposal of resources. Like for example:

```
using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
{
     //do some operations here
}
```

Comment: Thats how I usually handle disposing the context but there are 6 or 7 different methods in the service class so that leads to a lot of repeated code.

Comment: I agree that to some extent it does repeat the code; however to clean-up resources in a better manner, this code works the best.